# python write to file not working inside function

Tags: python-3.x, io

I am trying to write a basic file writing syntax inside a function but it doesn't work. The file is never created. When i do it outside function, it works fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Kindly point me in the right direction

```
def write():
    file=open("testfle.txt","w")
    file.write('hello')
    file.close()

    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saved your code in a file named `create.py` in IDLE and then ran it by calling your method `write()`, it works when you call the method `write()` like below.

It created a file named `testfle.txt` with content as hello

```
def write():
    file=open("testfle.txt","w")
    file.write('hello')
    file.close()
    return

## call write
write()
```

Also be very watchful of indentation when working with Python :).

Comment: np, happens a lot often then we think :)!. Please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 0):

Could be you mistyped `"testfile.txt"` as `"testfle.txt"`.